# TSql string search that mathes part of the string exact and part not

Tags: string, t-sql, search

I need to find a specific string pattern in Tsql.  I want the first part to be an exact match and the second part to be anything except a specific character.  Problem is I want the string to be allowed to end in that character.  For example  I want a query that will return all url's that match

```
www.test/%any thing but a '/'%/
```

so this would be returned

```
www.test/group/
```

and this would not

```
www.test/group/input/
```

I would prefer this to be in a single like statement to make adding arguments in this easier.

Comment: Why do you want that? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? It sounds like you have a hierarchy of pages and only want the branches at a certain level but not the leafs. That's a job for `hierarchyid`, not string matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it in single `LIKE`. `LIKE` is not `REGEX` and is limited.
With 2 `LIKE`s:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (href NVARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES('www.test/any thing but/asdsa/')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('www.test/any thing but/')


SELECT * FROM @t WHERE href LIKE N'www.test/%/' AND href NOT LIKE N'www.test/%/%/'
```

Output:

```
href
www.test/any thing but/
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me but I like the anser from Giorgi better +1

```
SELECT T.url 
  FROM ( values ('www.test/group/'), ('www.test/group/input/'), ('www.test/people/')
       ) as T(url)  
 WHERE T.url like 'www.test/%/'
   AND CHARINDEX ( '/' , T.url, CHARINDEX ( '/' , T.url, ( CHARINDEX ( '/' , T.url ) + 1 )  ) + 1 ) <= 0;
```